# Align a Gradient to center in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the gradient to be in the center of the page and text to be on that gradient.

```css
#grad1{
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom ,rgb(103, 53, 168),rgb(32, 147, 179));
            position: fixed;
            align-self: center;  
          }
```

```html
 <h1 id=grad1>Hello Guys</h1>
```

I want this heading to be on the top and at the center also place on the gradient. Also on scrolling I don't want it to go up with the page instead it should be visible at any time even if I have scrolled to the bottom of the page.

Comment: It sounds like you want the gradient to be on the `<html>` or the `<body>` tag, not the `<h1>`?

Comment: Could you reproduce your code by converting it to a snippet?

Comment: Read this [Runnable Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Strictly you aren't "*aligning a gradient to the center*" as said in the question. You want to align the h1 element to the center and you want it to have the gradient as a background. You also want it to remain in place when the user scrolls. Do you want scrolled content to go under the header or above it on scrolling and do you want it visible when it gets near the top, at the same level as the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the '**h1**' tag is not inside any block-level ancestor and '**fixed**' position property given on the '**h1**' tag, the **containing area** of the '**h1**' tag would be established by the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport) or the page area.

Mostly, [Containing area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) is the content area of the element's nearest block-level ancestor. In our case, containing area is the viewport.

So, if we apply **left** and **top** properties on the **h1** tag, this would we calculated based on the viewport width.

```
#grad1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom ,rgb(103, 53, 168),rgb(32, 147, 179));
  position: fixed;
  align-self: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}
```

The above will move the '**h1**' tag 50% left of the viewport width.
Now, we need to move back the **h1** tag text left by half of it's width. This could be achieved using **transform-translate** property.

For example -

```
#grad1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom ,rgb(103, 53, 168),rgb(32, 147, 179));
  position: fixed;
  align-self: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Hope this helps you!